# Daisy-chaining function calls on pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I encountered a scenario recently whilst working with a student, and I'm struggling to understand why the following example is failing.

I have a pointer to an object `Game`, and `Game` itself has a pointer to `vector<Pair>`. The failing line is the last line of of `main()`, where I am daisy-chaining methods:

`gamePointer->getPairs()->push_back(pair);`

In the above line, `getPairs()` returns a `vector<Pair>*`, and then `push_back()` is called to add a new `Pair` to the vector. This results in a `read access violation`. Interesting, swapping out the `Game`'s `vector<Pair>` with a `string`, say, allows me to write the following, and it works:

`gamePointer->getPairs()->append("B");`

I've simplified the problem and reproduced a full example:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Pair 
{
private:
    string previous;
    string next;

public:
    Pair();
    Pair(string previous, string next);

    string getPrevious();
    string getNext();

    void setPrevious(string previous);
    void setNext(string next);
};

class Game 
{
private:
    vector<Pair>* pairs;
public:
    Game();

    vector<Pair>* getPairs();
    void setPairs(vector<Pair>* pairs);
};


Pair::Pair()
{
    this->setPrevious("a");
    this->setNext("b");
}

Pair::Pair(string previous, string next)
{
    this->setPrevious(previous);
    this->setNext(next);
}

string Pair::getPrevious()
{
    return this->previous;
}

string Pair::getNext()
{
    return this->next;
}

void Pair::setPrevious(string previous)
{
    this->previous = previous;
}

void Pair::setNext(string next)
{
    this->next = next;
}

Game::Game()
{
    vector<Pair> pairs;
    pairs.reserve(10);

    this->setPairs(&pairs);
}

vector<Pair>* Game::getPairs()
{
    return this->pairs;
}

void Game::setPairs(vector<Pair>* pairs)
{
    this->pairs = pairs;
}

int main()
{
    Game game;
    Game* gamePointer = &game;

    Pair pair("Previous", "Next");
    gamePointer->getPairs()->push_back(pair);
}
```

Comment: Aren't you attempting to store, then access a vector pointer to a vector that is local to the Game constructor?

Comment: You should never store a pointer you acquire with `&` for later use. Your vector has ceased to be. (Cue ten commenters pointing out that "never" is a bit strong, to which my reply is "sometimes you can, but that doesn't mean that you should".)

Comment: I'm curious what you meant by "whilst working with a student".

Comment: About [using namespace std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)...

Comment: You should get used to implement constructor's initialiser list (not to be confused with `std::initialiser_list`!): `Pair() : previous("a"), next("b") { }`; you avoid default initialisation + assignment in favour to direct initialisation via parameters. Additionally, some types (references, non-default-constructible types) can *only* be initialised this way.

Comment: Constructor delegation (since C++11) makes code even nicer: `Pair() : Pair("a", "b") { }`, although, admitted, in given case, the gain is not that great...

Comment: That was immediately obvious once it was pointed out, thanks for all comments, especially those regarding pointers, constructor delegation, and the std namespace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Game::Game()
{
    vector<Pair> pairs; // DANGER!
    pairs.reserve(10);

    this->setPairs(&pairs); // ARGHH!
} // < pairs dies on this line
```

The `vector` named `pairs` only lives while the constructor is running. You store a pointer to this, but the pointed-to-object immediately goes out of scope!

Instead, just make the member a `vector` instead of a pointer:

```
class Game 
{
private:
    vector<Pair> pairs; // the vector itself is a member of Game
```

You could then make `getPairs` like this:

```
vector<Pair>* Game::getPairs() // return a pointer
{
    return &pairs;
}
```

or this:

```
vector<Pair>& Game::getPairs() // return a reference
{
    return pairs;
}
```

---

What you are doing currently is [**Undefined Behaviour**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) - this means your program is illegal, and anything could happen, **including appearing to work normally**.

"Appearing to work normally" is what you are seeing when you swap the `vector` for a `string` - your code is still broken, you just don't notice!

---

I can make an educated guess about why that happens, but this is in no way guaranteed.

`vector` behaviour:

- The `vector` object itself is on the **stack**, but it has to allocate a buffer on the **heap** using `new`.
- It then `delete`s this buffer when the `vector` goes out of scope at the end of `Game::Game()`.
- The `vector` object itself is no longer valid, but the memory just happens to not get overwritten before you next try to use it.
- You try to use the (no longer alive) `vector`, and the memory still happens to contain a pointer to the buffer. The buffer has been released, so you get a "read access violation" when trying to access it.

`string` behaviour:

- The `string` does **not** have a to allocate a buffer. It is a valid implementation of `std::string` for it to use a "Small String Optimisation", where small strings (let's say, up to 16 characters, for example) are stored directly inside the `string` object itself, rather than in an allocated buffer.
- Therefore the `string`, including the actual content, are on the **stack**.
- The `string` object goes out of scope at the end of `Game::Game()`, but the memory just happens to not get overwritten before you next try to use it.
- You try to use the (no longer alive) `string`, and the memory still happens to contain the valid "short string" magic.
- Because this is on the **stack**, not the **heap**, the memory hasn't actually been released. So trying to access it does **not** cause a "read access violation".
- It is still totally illegal though!

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the constructor of `Game`:

```
Game::Game()
{
    vector<Pair> pairs;
    pairs.reserve(10);

    this->setPairs(&pairs);
}
```

`pairs` is a local variable. It will be destroyed at the end of the constructor. Meaning `this->pairs` is a [dangling pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer). This can be fixed by simply allocating `this->pairs` in the constructor directly:

```
Game::Game()
{
    this->pairs = new vector<Pair>;
    this->pairs->reserve(10);
}
```

If you do this, always provide a deconstructor to clean up the allocated data:

```
Game::~Game()
{
    delete this->pairs;
}
```

This allows you to get rid of `setPairs`. In the end the class should look like this:

```
class Game
{
private:
    vector<Pair>* pairs;
public:
    Game();
    ~Game();

    vector<Pair>* getPairs();
};
```

To be honest, I don't really like your way of mixing classes like `vector` and raw pointers. In this simple example you don't even need a pointer at all. See [BoBTFish answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55417057/daisy-chaining-function-calls-on-pointers/55417151#55417151) on how you could make a pointer-less implementation. If you are, however, absolutely obligated to use pointers, use [`std::unique_ptr<std::vector<Pair>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) or [`std::shared_ptr<std::vector<Pair>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) instead. Please also consider getting rid of `using namespace std;` [<>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).